# "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped" error in android

Tags: android, listview, view

I'm trying a code of viewing the items inside of a directory, but every time I click the button where the code is coming from, the app closes and gives me an error saying "Unfortunately, YourApp has stopped.", and I don't know why is that.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewTextFiles extends ListActivity {

private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root;
private TextView myPath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewtextfiles);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    getDir(root);
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }else{
                item.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead()){
            getDir(path.get(position));
        }else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
        }
    }else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

    }
}
```

P.S I'm trying the code in a real device but without the use of usb cable (I export my .apk from my unit) because I'm having a problem with my unit which doesn't recognize my device when its connected through the usb cable, and as same as with the emulator, its having a problem with my processor which is I don't know how to fix.

Comment: When app getting crash on start or on click of ListView row?

Comment: I **strongly** recommend that you put programming aside for a while and get a working development environment. You need to be able to access stack traces from LogCat, and that will require a device or emulator for which you can use the development tools directly.

Comment: The app crashes when clicking the button which where the above is coming from. @prosper K

Comment: I've already tried my best to fix such problems with my unit but it seems unlucky for me to fix it. I've tried searching for universal driver for my device in order to get detected by my unit but I failed to find any as I'm having a local brand device which has a poor quality of support in terms like this. I've also tried fixing the problem with my emulator, but I've also failed to fix it because my unit doesn't have an Intel processor which based on what I've found, its the problem why the emulator doesn't work. @CommonsWare

Comment: "I'm having a local brand device which has a poor quality of support in terms like this" -- then buy a different device. I realize that this costs money, but so do lots of things related to software development and distribution. "I've also tried fixing the problem with my emulator" -- then try a different emulator, like Genymotion.

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir, its a local brand device.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I'm gonna try the Genymotion emulator.

Comment: ok which version of android does it have?

Comment: Android version: 4.0.4 / Ice Cream Sandwich. @Zeeshan Shabbir

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide this permission in android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Your Activity class should be as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

TextView myPath;
private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    getDir(root);

}


private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }else{
                item.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead()){
            getDir(path.get(position));
        }else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
        }
    }else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

    }
}
```

}

Your activity_main.xml file should be as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm already having this on my android manifest file yet it still does crash when I click the button where the code is coming from.

Comment: I executed your code in my device and it executed successfully. There may have problem in your listview or row of list.

Comment: Do you mean the layouts?

Comment: Yes. Try to use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of R.layout.row . Also make sure that your listView and textview are initialized correctly.

Comment: Extend Activity or AppCompatActivity instead of ListActivity. You are getting RuntimeException. Implement the Interface AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.

Comment: Would you mind posting all of that as an answer? I'd appreciate it so much because I'm in trouble getting all of that as I'm new to android developing.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this: `ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);`

Comment: Same as with the AppCompatActivity. When I try to fix that problem, it offers me to create a class. What should I do with it?